# sbt 0.13 multi project build, import packages across projects

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-plugin

I have a play project that I'd like to build with a `common` library that handles things like clients, services, utilities, etc...

My dir structure is like so:

```
.
├── build.sbt
├── myapp
│   ├── app
│   │   ├── controllers
│   │   │   └── HomeController.scala
│   │   └── views
│   │       ├── index.scala.html
│   │       └── main.scala.html
│   ├── conf
│   │   ├── application.conf
│   │   ├── logback.xml
│   │   ├── messages
│   │   └── routes
│   ├── public
│   │   ├── images
│   │   │   └── favicon.png
│   │   ├── javascripts
│   │   │   └── main.js
│   │   └── stylesheets
│   │       └── main.css
│   └── test
│       └── controllers
│           └── HomeControllerSpec.scala
├── myapp-common
│   └── src
│       └── main
│           └── TesterObject.scala
└── project
    ├── build.properties
    ├── plugins.sbt
    └── scaffold.sbt
```

My build.sbt is configured as follows:

```
lazy val commonSettings = Seq(
  version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT",
  scalaVersion := "2.12.3"
)

lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .settings(commonSettings)
  .aggregate(myapp, `myapp-common`)
  .dependsOn(myapp, `myapp-common`)

lazy val `myapp-common` = project
  .settings(commonSettings)                                                                                                                                                                                

lazy val myapp = project
  .enablePlugins(PlayScala)
  .settings(commonSettings)
  .settings(libraryDependencies += guice)
  .settings(libraryDependencies += "org.scalatestplus.play" %% "scalatestplus-play" % "3.1.2" % Test)
  .dependsOn(`myapp-common`)
```

While I am able to successfully run the play project with `sbt myapp/run`, it fails when I try to import a package defined in `myapp-common`.

For instance, if I have `myapp-common/src/main/TesterObject.scala`:

```
package tester

Object TesterObject {
    val testMe = 3
}
```

If I try to `import tester._` and then use `TesterObject.testMe` in `myapp/app/controllers/HomeController.scala`, the project fails during compilation since it can't find the package.

Can anyone point me in the right direction here? The sbt guide on multi-projects is a bit tough for me to parse for this particular problem. It seems like my dependencies are appropriately set up.